# C++ - building static library question

Tags: c++, linker, mingw

I built `libbz2` *(static variant)* using MinGW (GCC 4.5.0) compilation system and now try to import this library into my MSVS2008 project.

I've done these things already and everything worked fine, for example, with `zlib` (which means that created C libraries are actually interchangeable).

However, when doing the same with `libbz2`, I face some unknown troubles - when I compile my MSVS2008-project I receive the following error on linking stage:

```
unresolved external symbol ___chkstk referenced in function _bzopen_or_bzdopen
```

***I don't know why this happens (I think it's because some basic C runtimes are not fully compatible), but maybe someone knows how to fix this kind of error?***

*Maybe there is a manual way to somehow merge the implementation of MinGW-based `___chkstk` into `libbz2` static library?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your answer, but I think there's an easier (automatic) way of doing the manual merging of object files: use the CFLAG `-static-libgcc`, which will link in the necessary functions (what you are describing and doing manually).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, I found the answer.

*Basically, you can simply link to `libgcc.a / libgcc.lib` which was used when building the library.*

The more convenient way that deals with the `___chkstk` problem only means doing something like `ar x libgcc.a` (which produces many .o files) and then merging your `libbz2` object files with `__chkstk.o` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be in linker options e.g. **LDFLAGS=-static**, while LDFLAGS=-static-libgcc still gives dynamically linked binaries...with any test.c:

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -static-libgcc test.o
ldd a.out
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

gcc -c test.c
gcc -static test.o
ldd a.out
    not a dynamic executable
```

For librarian, simply use ar

```
ar q libtest.a <path>/libgcc.a
```